# "bind: address already in use" when trying to create my own api and using apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, http

I am using `apache2` webserver on `ec2` instance and I am trying to use a simple `go` script that I can do a `get` request on.

My `go` scipt looks like this:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
)

func say_hi(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Printf("\033[0;32m%v\033[0m\n", r)
        fmt.Fprint(w, fmt.Sprint("Hi"))
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/say_hi", say_hi)

    ip_address := "0.0.0.0:8080"

    fmt.Printf("Set up ip address: %s\n", ip_address)
    error := http.ListenAndServe(ip_address, nil)
        if error != nil {
        fmt.Println(error)
    }

}
```

When I run the script on my `ec2` server I get the following error:

```
listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8080: bind: address already in use
```

I really don't understand why I get this error.

I tried to investigate further

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-37-75:~$ socklist
type  port      inode     uid    pid   fd  name
tcp     22       8895       0      0    0  
tcp   3306       9160     106      0    0  
tcp     22       9569       0      0    0  
tcp  44403          0       0      0    0  
udp  18341       7860       0      0    0  
udp     68       7939       0      0    0
```

And it does not seem like anything is using those ports.

I have ports `80` and `8080` open:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-37-75:~$ netstat -nlp | grep "80"
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

and my `ports.conf` file looks like this:

```
Listen 80
Listen 8080

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

I am complete beginner, so I might be missing some really obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a running program listening on port 8080, as evidenced by your `netstat` output. You seem to indicate that it is Apache. You will need to reconfigure Apache so that it does not listen on port 8080, or choose a different port on which to run your Go program.

Comment: I guess this is where I am confused, if I try to run my `go` program on, say, port 8088, then it is useless because I don't have that port open. It seemed to me that specifying ports in `ports.conf` is the way to open ports, but it does not seem to be the case because nothing but Apache can use them after that. Is there another way to open a port?

Comment: What do you mean by "open" a port?

Comment: Let's say, I want to use port `8088` in my `go` program, I want to be able to use that port (right now I can't use it). This is what I mean by "open".

Comment: That is generally called "listening" or "binding" to a port. In this instant, Apache is listening on that port, so your Go program cannot. The term "opening" a port is almost always in reference to a firewall, if one is in use.

Comment: @Akavall P.S. Since you're new to Go, I highly recommend reading [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html). This will give you a good jumpstart on the language, explain some non-obvious things, and provide some best practices.

Comment: I think in this case my problem is caused by misunderstanding of how http servers work, not Go, but I could certainly get better at Go too :).